# Fill categorical NaN values based upon proportion within groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataset that consists of entirely categorical features.

One column only has missing values: 2480 NaN out of 8124.

I can successfully fill the NaN values based upon the percentage of existing categorical values:

```
print(df['stalk-root'].value_counts(normalize=True), '\n')
```

yields:

```
b    0.669029
e    0.198441
c    0.098512
r    0.034018
```

I then use these percentages to fill the missing values with this:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934140/fill-missing-values-by-a-ratio-of-other-values-in-pandas
df['stalk-root'] = df['stalk-root'].fillna(pd.Series(np.random.choice(['b', 'e', 'c', 'r'],
                                                     p=[0.669029, 0.198441, 0.098512, 0.034018], size=len(df))))
```

It works perfectly.

However, I was curious as to what the value_counts of column df['stalk-root'] looked like if I grouped by the 'class' column.

```
print(df.groupby('class')['stalk-root'].value_counts(normalize=True), '\n')
```

yields:

```
e      b             0.550459
       e             0.247706
       c             0.146789
       r             0.055046
p      b             0.860853
       e             0.118738
       c             0.020408
```

That's a pretty big difference.  Big enough that I want to now modify my NaN fill procedure to first
groupby class, then fill via percentage, as above.

I have done this before with numerical columns and mean(), but this is different in that I am manually
filling the percentages in np.random.choice() based upon the results from value_counts(normalize=True).

I don't know how to say:  groupby class, run ['stalk-root'].value_counts(normalize=True), then take those values and feed then into fillna(np.random.choice() like I did above.

I will have two completely different sets of filling values, and 'r' is only present in one of them.

One will be (for class 'e'):

```
np.random.choice(['b', 'e', 'c', 'r'],
                   p=[0.550459, 0.247706, 0.146789, 0.055046], size=len(df)
```

The other (for class 'p') will be:

```
np.random.choice(['b', 'e', 'c'],
                   p=[0.860853, 0.118738, 0.020408], size=len(df)
```

The second issue I have is with size=len(df).  This would have to be the size of each grouping (I assume), and they are not the same size.

[data file from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/mushroom-classification)

Comment: can you provide a sample? say `df[['class', 'stalk-root']].head(50).to_dict()`

Comment: @RichieV, I had to edit my question to fit the output you requested.  See above.

Comment: I am using the mushrooms.csv dataset from Kaggle.

Comment: there are no `NaN`s in that dataset... did you modify it after downloading?

Comment: @RichieV, Yes:  ```df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="utf-8", na_values='?')```

Comment: `df.info()` there are no null values in the dataset. `RangeIndex: 8124 entries, 0 to 8123` & all columns have `8124 non-null` values

Comment: 11  stalk-root                5644 non-null   object   That dataset uses '?'.  I tell pandas via na_values='?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood, but could you not do this:

```
class_e = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['b', 'e', 'c', 'r'],
                   p=[0.550459, 0.247706, 0.146789, 0.055046], size=len(df)))
class_p = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['b', 'e', 'c'],
                   p=[0.860853, 0.118738, 0.020408], size=len(df))

df.loc[df['class'] == e, 'stalk-root'] = df['stalk-root'].fillna(class_e)
df.loc[df['class'] == p, 'stalk-root'] = df['stalk-root'].fillna(class_p)
```

Comment: e_size = df[df['class'] == e, :].size.  If I use ```e_size = len(df[df['class'] == 'e'])``` the error is resolved, but the result is incorrect.  Your initial solution seems to be correct.  It has to cycle through the entire df since the affected row could be anywhere.  I didn't realize that at first.  If your revised solution was contained within a groupby() object, then I think it would be correct.

Comment: I can even see exactly how many lines are filled by each part of your first solution by commenting out the ```df.loc[df['class'] == e, 'stalk-root']``` lines one at a time.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. If you want it within the groupby @RichieV's solution should be accepted :)

Comment: It doesn't matter to me.  Your initial solution worked fine.  Remove your edit to put the initial solution back in place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `groupby`

```
was_null = df['stalk-root'].isna()

for _, gdf in df.groupby('class')['stalk-root']:
    vc = gdf.value_counts(normalize=True)
    df.loc[gdf.loc[gdf.isna()].index, 'stalk-root'] = (
        np.random.choice(vc.index, gdf.isna().sum(), p=vc)
    )
```

Verifying the output

```
# old distribution
print(df[was_null].groupby('class')['stalk-root'].value_counts(normalize=True))

class  stalk-root
e      b             0.561111
       e             0.236111
       c             0.140278
       r             0.062500
p      b             0.865341
       e             0.117045
       c             0.017614
Name: stalk-root, dtype: float64


# new distribution
print(df.groupby('class')['stalk-root'].value_counts(normalize=True))

class  stalk-root
e      b             0.552281
       e             0.245722
       c             0.145675
       r             0.056321
p      b             0.862870
       e             0.117978
       c             0.019152
Name: stalk-root, dtype: float64
```