# Is there a way to impute categorical values while maintaining the proportions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nan, categorical-data

I have a data set that is almost perfect but there is a column called Refferer which has 3672 missing values, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o60fk.png) you can find an image about the current data set. The Refferer column, contains categorical attributes and I would like to replace all the NaN cells keeping the proportion of strings that are already populating the column (find the proportions [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivjuo.png)).

Is there a way to automatically do that with a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: Do you want to replace the NaN randomly?

Comment: No, I would like to replace the NaN values with the values that are already in the column and in the same proportion, that is:
Ford: 46.5%
Browser: 36.6%
Dealer: 13.9%
Other: 2.8%

Comment: There are many ways of assigning values and keeping the proportion. Do you want to do it randomly?

Comment: Sure, I don't mind doing it randomly as long as the proportions are maintained.

Comment: You might find it useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934140/fill-missing-values-by-a-ratio-of-other-values-in-pandas

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was just looking for. Works perfectly.